# Call the callback() after callback of another function completes

Tags: node.js

I have a method that I want to do some requests and calculations before it executes the callback. I have found many people suggesting to use the [async](https://npmjs.org/package/async) module but it still doesn't wait for the callback to complete before calling the callback. This is example code of what I am trying to accomplish.

**loop.js**

```
var ex_obj = require('./ex_obj');
var array2loop = [
  arr1 = new ex_obj(),
  arr2 = new ex_obj(),
  arr3 = new ex_obj()
];

var loop = function(){
  for(var i=0; i < array2loop.length; i++){
    array2loop[i].incrementNumber(function log(){
      console.log('Should fire last: ' + array2loop[i].number);
    });
  }
  setTimeout(loop, 5000);
};

loop();
```

**ex_obj.js**

```
var async = require('async');
var ex_obj = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.number = 0;
  self.incrementNumber = function(callback){
    self.number = ++self.number;
    // This setTimeout is a placeholder for a url request
    // that I don't know how long will take.
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('Should fire first: '+self.number);
    }, 2000);
    callback();
  };
};
module.exports = ex_obj;
```

When run as is I get the following

```
Should fire last: 1
Should fire last: 1
Should fire last: 1
Should fire first: 1
Should fire first: 1
Should fire first: 1
Should fire last: 2
...etc
```

If I make the following changes I get a "Cannot read property 'number' of undefined" error:

**ex_obj.js**

```
  self.incrementNumber = function(callback){
    self.number = ++self.number;
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('Should fire first: '+self.number);
      callback();
    }, 2000);
  };
```

So I tried to use async.series to only call the callback after the timeout ran

**ex_obj.js**

```
async.series([
  function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('Should fire first '+self.number);
    }, 2000)}],
  callback()
);
```

This still resulted in the the output above. I know this is a commonly asked question but I can't seem to find a solution that deals with a callback inside the callback. Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
var ex_obj = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.number = 0;
  self.incrementNumber = function (callback) {
    self.number = ++self.number;
    setTimeout(callback, 2000);
    console.log('Should fire first: ' + self.number);
  };
};

var array2loop = [
  arr1 = new ex_obj(),
  arr2 = new ex_obj(),
  arr3 = new ex_obj()
];

var loop = function () {
  array2loop.forEach(function (element) {
    element.incrementNumber(function () {
      console.log('Should fire last: ' + element.number);
    });
  });
  setTimeout(loop, 5000);
};

loop();
```

Output:

```
Should fire first: 1
Should fire first: 1
Should fire first: 1
Should fire last: 1
Should fire last: 1
Should fire last: 1
Should fire first: 2
Should fire first: 2
Should fire first: 2
Should fire last: 2
Should fire last: 2
Should fire last: 2
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @micnic the trouble with your solution is that the setTimeout I'm using in this example is a placeholder for url requests and calculations. I don't really know how long it will take. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear before, this is my first post and I tried to be as detailed as possible.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was chasing the wrong problem this whole time. I switched to using a forEach and it works like a charm.

Comment: @user3009902, glad to hear this :) As you may observed you was trying to acces an element which was after the end of the array, try always use closures when you are writing asynchronous code.